# Step through an assembly language program one statement at a time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to step through an assembly language program one statement at a time, in order to see the state of each variable at each line of the program? I've heard that it's possible to do this, but I haven't yet been able to find relevant information anywhere.

Comment: The following Google search hasn't given me any useful results so far: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=step+through+each+instruction+in+an+assembly+language+program&oq=step+through+each+instruction+in+an+assembly+language+program&gs_l=hp.3...1129.11176.0.11342.69.62.4.1.1.0.206.5896.41j20j1.62.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.wz_4aE5uSwk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.dmQ&fp=d5bbde17dd6cca0a&biw=1366&bih=596

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just use the debugger as you would with C/C++ code, but in a view that shows the disassembly. If there is no source available, that's the default. Otherwise you need to select "Go To Disassembly" in the context menu.

You will need debug information if you want to inspect variables properly, though of course you can look at registers, memory, etc. even without that.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, how would you activate the context menu that shows "Go To Disassembly"? Which part of the editor should I right-click in order to see this context menu?

Comment: Also, which version(s) of Visual Studio does this answer apply to?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to put a breakpoint on the first assembly instruction you care about, and then simply run.  VS will hit the breakpoint, and you can single-step there.  At the breakpoint you can also right-click->gotoDissambly.

Comment: I've noticed that it's possible to step through a program one statement at a time using *Debug --> Step Over*.