# Base64 Assembler Fill Array Error "Operands different sizes" Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, base64, inline-assembly

Im trying to make a Base64Encode in inline assembler in Visual Studio.

I got this func

```
char* Base64Encode(char* data, int len)
{
// Tabelle mit den Zeichen für die Codierung
const char* encodeTable = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
//
char* result;   


if (len > 0)            // sonst gibt es nichts zu tun ...
{
    int encodedLength   = ((len + 2) / 3) * 4;      // effektiv die Ganzzahlfassung von ceil(length/3)*4
    result = new char[encodedLength+1];             // +1 wg. Null-Terminierung
    _asm
    {           
        mov esi,data
        mov edi,encodeTable

        xor eax, eax
        // get 3 bytes
        mov ah, byte ptr[esi]
        mov al, byte ptr[esi+1]
        shl eax,16
        mov ah, byte ptr[esi+2]

        //
        mov edx,eax
        shl eax,6

        shr edx, 26
        mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]    
        mov [result],bl

        //
        mov edx, eax
        shl eax, 6                                    

        shr edx, 26
        mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]            
        mov[result+1], bl

        //manipulate in edx bitset3
        mov edx, eax
        shl eax, 6

        shr edx, 26
        mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]
        mov[result+2], bl

        //manipulate in edx bitset4
        mov edx, eax
        shl eax, 6

        shr edx, 26
        mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]
        mov[result+3], bl


    }
}
else
{
    result = "";
}
return result;
}
```

The encoding is working proper, I have in bl always the right letter, but the output is not working ( result array doesn't fill with the letters, im getting the error that the operands have different sizes, I am only allowed to make changes in the __asm function ) .

Could somebody help me how to fill the result-array with the letters I get in bl? Debugging always shows me the right letters in the bl ' s if i comment out all the result lines.

EDIT:
[image]

I  get nothing in the result array when i use the byte ptr.

Any ideas?

EDIT2:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does stepping through the assembler code suggest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905769/step-through-an-assembly-language-program-one-statement-at-a-time

Comment: not sure if thats what u meant, in the edit2 you see there is an A in bl and in the next step it should be in the result array, but the result array is just 0 '/0'

Comment: can't be so hard to make an base64 encode in that __asm :(

Comment: Consider this. `mov [result],bl` (should probably be better written as `mov byte ptr [result],bl` moves the contents of `bl` to `result` but `result` is actually a pointer to a character string (returned by `new`). You are missing a level of indirection. You have literally changed the _pointer_ itself,  not the data at the pointer contained in _result_ .

Comment: hm okay i think i get the point but how do i fill the array now with the letters ? :D  I am done and have no more ideas

Comment: Well you need to get the _contents_ of the variable _result_ (which would be the pointer returned by `new`), at the start of your asm block. Move that address into a register (`ecx` for example) with something like `mov ecx, dword ptr [result]` . ECX should now be the pointer of your actual buffer. Now wherever you used `result` in your asm block change it to `ecx`. So `mov [result],bl` would become `mov byte ptr [ecx],bl`, `mov[result+1], bl` would become `mov byte ptr [ecx+1], bl` etc.

Comment: that is working thanks

Comment: it said "operands of different sizes" not sure if thats the correct english translation of the error ( got it in german :b ) , but yeah there was an error tho.

Comment: hmh one last small thing, how do i implement a counter variable there? if i make result + 1 , +2 and so on i will overwrite if i make a loop around it . i need something like i do in c in for-loops like i++ ..

Comment: im using MS Visual studio  2013 by the way

Comment: That is a different question altogether. You could pick an unused register like `EDX` as a loop variable. You can do things like `mov byte ptr [ecx + edx], bl`, `mov byte ptr [ecx + edx + 3], bl` for example. The last one is based indexed plus displacement addressing.

Comment: okay I will play around a bit with that then thank you tho

Comment: I've added an answer with the information about the indirection etc, summing up my comments about the original question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is a matter of indirection. You define and initialize a  variable `result` like this in the *C++* code:

```
char* result; 
result = new char[encodedLength+1];
```

`result` is a memory location that holds a pointer to an array of characters returned by `new`. `result` is not the memory location where data will be stored, but contains a pointer to that data area. You then access it in the *ASM* block like this:

```
mov [result],bl
```

The compiler/assembler(*MASM*) warned that there was an operand mismatch when it said *Operands different sizes*. It knew that `result` was the location of a 32-bit pointer (not single characters). Since `result` is the address containing a pointer the code above would have moved the contents of `bl` to the memory location `result`. This had the effect of changing the pointer (returned by `new`) not what `result` was pointing at.

You need to deal with indirection here. You want to get the address that is stored in `result` and use that as a *base* for memory addressing. You can choose an available register like *ECX* and *MOV* the contents of `result` into it. You could do that with something like this at the top of your *ASM* block:

```
mov ecx, dword ptr [result]
```

This takes the 32-bit(dword) value at memory location `result` and stores that in *ECX*. Now that we have the memory location to the beginning of the character buffer we can now modify all references of `result` in the *ASM* block and change it to *ECX*. Examples:

```
mov [result],bl
```

would become:

```
mov byte ptr [ecx],bl
```

and

```
mov[result+1], bl
```

would become:

```
mov byte ptr [ecx+1], bl
```

The second example is called [base plus displacement (or offset) addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Base_plus_offset.2C_and_variations) . That link also describes all the addressing modes on x86. If you were using 16-bit code (which you aren't) there are some extra restrictions in the register choices that can be use for base and indexing.

As well *user3144770* also pointed out that you didn't null terminate your string (you only allocated space for it), so at the bottom of your *ASM* block you should have probably used something like:

```
mov byte ptr[ecx+4], 0
```

With the changes above your code could look something like:

```
char* Base64Encode(char* data, int len)
{
    // Tabelle mit den Zeichen für die Codierung
    const char* encodeTable = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    //
    char* result;

    if (len > 0)            // sonst gibt es nichts zu tun ...
    {
        int encodedLength = ((len + 2) / 3) * 4;      // effektiv die Ganzzahlfassung von ceil(length/3)*4
        result = new char[encodedLength + 1];         // +1 wg. Null-Terminierung
        _asm
        {
            mov esi, data
            mov edi, encodeTable

                mov ecx, dword ptr [result]
                xor eax, eax
                // get 3 bytes
                mov ah, byte ptr[esi]
                mov al, byte ptr[esi + 1]
                shl eax, 16
                mov ah, byte ptr[esi + 2]

                //
                mov edx, eax
                shl eax, 6

                shr edx, 26
                mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]
                mov byte ptr [ecx], bl

                //
                mov edx, eax
                shl eax, 6

                shr edx, 26
                mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]
                mov byte ptr [ecx + edx + 1], bl

                //manipulate in edx bitset3
                mov edx, eax
                shl eax, 6

                shr edx, 26
                mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]
                mov byte ptr [ecx + 2], bl

                //manipulate in edx bitset4
                mov edx, eax
                shl eax, 6

                shr edx, 26
                mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]
                mov byte ptr [ecx + 3], bl

                mov byte ptr[ecx + 4], 0
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's enough to write `byte ptr`

```
mov bl, byte ptr[edi + edx]    
mov byte ptr[result], bl
```

Also you don't actually do the null-termination. ( +1 wg. Null-Terminierung)

```
mov byte ptr[result+4], 0
```

Comment: i used that, then i just get nothing ( edited my thread ) any ideas?